# Sonarqube is not working after update

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I updated SonarQube to 4.2 and it is not working at Jenkins now. T.T

Jenkins and SonarQube are installed in same server and I'm using mysql.
also, Jenkins setting for SonarQube is pointing the mysql db.

... and Maven version in Jenkins is 3.0.5

I don't set the sonar maven plugin in the java project.

It worked fine with Sonar 3.4.1 and I didn't change any setting on Jenkins after update the SonarQube.

here is error trace.

```
    [ERROR] Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 16.495s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 15 06:10:08 GMT 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 20M/89M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) on project java-utils: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2 -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) on project java-utils: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:109)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:67)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:109)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2
        at org.sonar.maven.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:37)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:175)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:104)
        ... 23 more`enter code here`
    Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:66)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:63)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:43)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.selectByNameAndLanguage(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.core.qualityprofile.db.QualityProfileDao.selectByNameAndLanguage(QualityProfileDao.java:181)
        at org.sonar.core.qualityprofile.db.QualityProfileDao.selectByNameAndLanguage(QualityProfileDao.java:188)
        at org.sonar.batch.rule.ModuleQProfiles.loadQProfile(ModuleQProfiles.java:105)
        at org.sonar.batch.rule.ModuleQProfiles.(ModuleQProfiles.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:631)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getMemberArguments(SingleMemberInjector.java:61)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.getMemberArguments(MethodInjector.java:100)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:112)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:631)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1033)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1025)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:199)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:194)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:187)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:56)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:44)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:132)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:173)
        ... 24 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: I have this issue but I do not think it is related to an SQ update. `ERROR: Caused by: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2`

Answer (score 2):

You're facing http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5196 that is fixed in the upcoming version (4.3). It means that you have two identical quality profiles (same name but different case) for the same language. Could you delete one and run again an analysis?

Comment: I removed some quality profile for java from Quality Profiles. but still I have same exception. did I remove right profile?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not update your SonarQube database. To do this start your SonarQube like

```
http://<sonarqubeserver>/setup
```

and follow the instructions there.

This update is sometimes necessary if the upgrade introduces database changes. Nevertheless SonarQube should post a maintenance message if you start it in your browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had updated the database right after update the Sonaqube. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was the exact same issue. I was 2 quality profiles with the same exact name (after upgrading sonar from 3.5 to 4.2).
I remove the old "sonar way" and keep the new "sonar way" quality profile and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I found bunch of "Sonar way" profiles for each language profiles, in actually, I focussed on JAVA profile only.

I renamed all the profiles. 
like,

- Groovy-Sonar way (from Sonar way for Groovy profiles)
- Java-Sonar way (from Sonar way for Java profiles)
- JavaScript-Sonar way (from Sonar way for JavaScript profiles)
- PHP-Sonar Way (from Sonar way for PHP profiles)

But PHP profiles had "Sonar way" and "Sonar Way". I removed one of them.

and anyway, running Sonar from Jenkins has worked successfully now!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your project that is causing the error in the SonarQube web-interface and then re-scan the project.